# How to enter numeric values to Android Numpad using Appium?

Tags: java, android, testing, automation, appium

I have tried using :

1. send_keys method:

`driver.send_keys("12345678");`

This does not give any error , yet doesn't even enter any text.

2.Sending key event

```
HashMap numKeyObject = new HashMap();
numKeyObject.put("keycode", 145);
numKeyObject.put("keycode", 146);
numKeyObject.put("keycode", 147);
numKeyObject.put("keycode", 148);
numKeyObject.put("keycode", 149);
numKeyObject.put("keycode", 150);
((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", numKeyObject);
```

This gives an error saying 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented'

I'm using appium java client 2.2.0

Answer (score 3):

Below are the ways to numeric values from android numeric keypad

1) **driver.sendkeyEvent(int key);**

List Of Key codes:
a - z-> 29 - 54

"0" - "9"-> 7 - 16

BACK BUTTON - 4, MENU BUTTON - 82

UP-19, DOWN-20, LEFT-21, RIGHT-22

SELECT (MIDDLE) BUTTON - 23

SPACE - 62, SHIFT - 59, ENTER - 66, BACKSPACE - 67

You can get the explaination of keycodes here:
https://code.google.com/p/androhid/wiki/Keycodes

**2) driver.findElementByID("LocatorID").sendKeys("123");**

please leave question in comment

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this way:

```
driver.findElementByID("locator").sendKeys("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The best and easier way is :

element.setValue("");

for eg:
@AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.life.login:id/et_pin")
private MobileElement unlockPhone;
public void unlockPhone() {
    unlockPhone.setValue("1111");
    System.out.println("Lockscreen Unlocled");
}
```